# Combine scalar query and results from a subquery that returns multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to combine two queries one a scalar query and other a multiple column subquery to return the data in one row?

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME() DB,
    (select SettingValue from Settings where SettingName = 'XYZ') 'Is XYZ',
    (SELECT Department.DeptName, COUNT(*) 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT substring(Source, len(Source) - 17, 14) AS DeptId FROM AuditLog) LogDept 
        inner join Department on LogDept.DeptId = Department.DeptId
        GROUP BY Department.DeptName)
```

I want the result like

| DB | Is XYZ | DeptName | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST | True | FIN | 20 |
| TEST | True | HR | 12 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally just add them to your sub-query and make it your main query.

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME() DB
    , (SELECT SettingValue FROM Settings WHERE SettingName = 'XYZ') 'Is XYZ'
    , D.DeptName, COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT substring(Source, len(Source) - 17, 14) AS DeptId
    FROM AuditLog
) LogDept AS LD
INNER JOIN Department AS D ON D.DeptId = LD.DeptId
GROUP BY D.DeptName;
```

And I recommend the use of short table aliases as I have demonstated.